# Why was Yam Suf necessary according to Rabenu Chananel?

Tags: beshalach, yetziat-mitzrayim, geonim

What is Rabenu Chananel's explanation for the reason Hashem couldn't just take the Jewish people through the short route and took them on the long journey through the desert?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Rivka.  Nice question.  Is this a question for which you already know the answer?  If not, what made you think to ask it?

Comment: Can you explain what Rabenu Chananel said that prompted this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rabbeinu Bachaye to Shemos 13:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14069&st=&pgnum=205)

> וכתב רבינו חננאל ז״ל שהוליכם דרך המדבר לסבה
>    אחרת והיא כדי להרבות להם אותות ומופתים כי
>    אילו הוליכם דרך ארץ פלשתים הקרוב ויתן הקב"ה
>    בלבם שיתנו להם רשות לעבור דרך ארצם ושלא יעכבו
>    אותם כלל היה האות קל ועל כן חייבה החכמה
>    להסב אותם דרך המדבר להיות האותות רבים
>    וגדולים כירידת המן ועלית השלו והוצאת מים מן
>    הצור כי כפי מה שנתרחקו מן הישוב יגדל האות
>    והמופת שיעמוד מין האדם כמקומות ההם

Summary:  In order to do more miracles.  By going through the desert, and far from civilization, it allowed for the abundant miracles of the manna etc., which would not have happened had they gone straight through.